# Error using K&R style function definition

Tags: c, compiler-errors, kernighan-and-ritchie

I got the following error at compile time.I know it sounds wrong,but what's the exact message compiler is trying to convey:
error: conflicting types for 'fun'
error: previous decalaration of fun was here:

```
 int main( )
 {
    extern int fun(float);
    int a;
    a=fun(3.14F);
    printf("%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}

int fun( aa )
float aa;
{
    return( (int) aa);
}
```

Comment: What's up with the old-fashioned function definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

K&R-style function declarations aren't quite the same as modern style ones.  In particular, the *default argument promotions* take place, making your `float` parameter not quite legal.  You have two choices to fix your problem:

1. Change `fun` to accept a `double` parameter instead of a `float`.
2. Change the definition of `fun` to a standard-C-style function definition:

   ```
   int fun(float aa)
   {
       return aa;
   }
   ```

   I also removed the unnecessary cast & parentheses.

As an aside, if you are a beginner, you might find [clang](http://clang.llvm.org) helpful - it sometimes provides much better error messages.  For your program, for example:

```
example.c:13:7: warning: promoted type 'double' of K&R function parameter is not
      compatible with the parameter type 'float' declared in a previous
      prototype [-Wknr-promoted-parameter]
float aa;
      ^
example.c:5:25: note: previous declaration is here
    extern int fun(float);
                        ^
```

Comment: A third option, if for some reason you insist on using an old-style definition, is to declare `fun` correctly inside `main`, changing `extern int fun(float);` to `extern int fun();`. Or just drop the `extern` declaration and move the definition of `fun` before `main`.